# Excel SQL - Value from column / range cells

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-office

I'm trying to retrieve data from column A (cell A1 to A20000) from sheet `data`. When I put this query i get error: "Unexpected extra token `Dim`". What I do wrong?

```
SELECT 
    OZATI_etc.Account, 
    OZATI_etc.Equipment
FROM 
    OZATI_etc
WHERE 
    OZATI_etc.Account IN (SELECT * FROM [data$A1:A20000])
ORDER BY
    OZATI_etc.Account

    Dim currentRow As Integer
    Dim str As String
    currentRow = 1
    Do While (sheets("data").Range("A" & currentRow).Value <> "")
        str = str & ",'" & sheets("data").Range("A" & currentRow).Value & "'"
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Loop
    str = Mid(str, 2)
```

Comment: Possible causes include: Login and password provided in the company information are incorrect. ODBC Data Source is configured incorrectly.

Comment: No I see error with identifier